# PHP echo gettext from a class

Tags: php, class, methods, gettext

Im kinda new to classes and try to return an array and a gettext string from a method, so I can validate later the array and echo out the string.
I think it's more of a syntax problem due to my lack of knowledge - but I cant figure out how to avoid that Warning with illegal offset string. The simplified the code is below. Hope someone can help?

**class.php**

```
class test {
  private $a = 1;
  public function validate() {
    
    if($this->a == 1) {
        //return _("SUCCESS"); <-this works fine
        
        //I would like to return array AND gettext message together
        //something like this I tried:        
        return array('status'=>1, 'message'=>_("SUCCESS"));
    }
}
$test = new test();
```

**index.php**

```
  $message = $test->validate();

 //echo $message; <-this works fine

 //But when I try this, I get Illegal offset string Warning...
 echo $message['status'];
```

Comment: `var_dump($message)` after the call to validate to ensure it contains what you think it does.

Comment: _"`echo $message; <-this works fine`"_ prints `Array`?

Comment: `$test = new test();` should be in index.php, not in class.php.

Comment: Thank you guys, var_dump contained the values i searched for. And moving $test = new test(); to index.php solved it completely. But why I cant put it in class.php, just im curious.

Comment: I think you can leave it in the class script. But it makes no sense. The flow of your system is in the index script, and the class script should work as a library, and do not participate in the main flow.

Answer (score 0):

### class.php

```php
class test {
    private $a = 1;
    public function validate()
    {
        if($this->a == 1)
            return array('status'=>1);
    }
}
```

### index.php

```php
include('class.php');
$test = new test();
$message = $test->validate();
echo $message['status'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this only returns status array. The problem is solved above, i had to put $test = new test(); into index.php, not in class.php

Comment: Yes i agree with you. it is the right way. and now makes sense !